# pure-ftpd fails to install (Couldn't examine directory /etc/pure-ftpd/conf)

Tags: 14.04, pure-ftpd

I've been having some issues with setting up pure-ftpd.  I decided to completely remove it before reinstalling it again, however I accidentally remove the configuration files before uninstalling the program with `apt-get`.  My issue is now reinstalling (or attempting to) causes the installing to fail with the following output;

```
root@server:~# apt-get install pure-ftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfile-copy-recursive-perl openbsd-inetd update-inetd
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libfile-copy-recursive-perl openbsd-inetd pure-ftpd update-inetd
0 to upgrade, 4 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/277 kB of archives.
After this operation, 929 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-copy-recursive-perl.
(Reading database ... 54154 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfile-copy-recursive-perl_0.38-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-copy-recursive-perl (0.38-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package update-inetd.
Preparing to unpack .../update-inetd_4.43_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-inetd (4.43) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openbsd-inetd.
Preparing to unpack .../openbsd-inetd_0.20091229-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openbsd-inetd (0.20091229-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pure-ftpd.
Preparing to unpack .../pure-ftpd_1.0.36-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pure-ftpd (1.0.36-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libfile-copy-recursive-perl (0.38-1) ...
Setting up update-inetd (4.43) ...
Setting up openbsd-inetd (0.20091229-2ubuntu3) ...
 * Stopping internet superserver inetd                                                                                                                           [ OK ]
 * Not starting internet superserver: no services enabled
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up pure-ftpd (1.0.36-1.1) ...
Starting ftp server: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-wrapper: Couldn't examine directory /etc/pure-ftpd/conf: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript pure-ftpd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package pure-ftpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pure-ftpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried creating the `/etc/pure-ftpd/`, `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/` and `/etc/pure-ftpd/auth/` directories again however this results in no configuration files actually being created and this is something I want.

How would I fully remove pure-ftpd and then reinstall it from scratch?

Comment: Adding the directories & files back manually seems to fix the issue.  However, uninstalling pure-ftpd leaves the files behind (since I'm guessing they haven't been created with the installer) so I would still like to now how to completely purge pure-ftpd, uninstalling it fully allowing me to reinstall it once again.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this issue.  It appears pure-ftpd-common was also installed, I would think this package works with the configuration files and the following command solve this issue;

```
apt-get remove --purge pure-ftpd pure-ftpd-common
```